# What pressure to take in surface tension question?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, fluid

Pressure inside a water droplet is $0.32 N/cm^2$ if surface tension of liquid is $0.095 N/m$. We have to find the radius of the bubble

since it's a water droplet the formula used is $$P_i-P_o=\frac{2T}{R}$$
The $P_i$ is internal pressure wehreas $P_0$ is external pressure so the $P_0$ should be taken in consideration but the solution of the question directly puts $0.32$ in place of pressure difference. where I am doing wrong in the question.

Comment: How does 0.32 N/cm2 compare to atmospheric pressure?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer sorry - you and me both mate!

Comment: @Wasabi answer is already in the question, OP just needed a pointer not a 5 page essay.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered that the solution is assuming that the pressure is gauge pressure ie above atmospheric...

So that means if you have the bubble pressure as an absolute pressure reading and you subtract the external atmospheric pressure you end up with the difference which is the value given in the solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to flesh it out. For inspiration, read [this discussion on short answers](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/377/1832) (in the context of comments, but much of what is discussed applies to very short answers such as this one).

Answer (score 0):

I think , a good hint is, the given value is the gauge pressure value.

Comment: Let's see how long it takes @Wasabi to give you a comment.... Let us hope he does not discriminate...

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to flesh it out. For inspiration, [read this discussion on short answers](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/377/1832) (in the context of comments, but much of what is discussed applies to very short answers such as this one). And @SolarMike, let's keep comments on-topic, please.

Comment: Both answers are succinct and on-topic.... and correct